# Unity3D in WebGL the Player doesn't have animations

Tags: unity, 3d, webgl, build-process

I using Unity 2019.2.14f1 to create a simple 3D game.

I want to build the project for WebGL, but, even though the player has animations on Unity, in the web the Player doesn't have animations even though it jumps and moves around [[as you can see here]](http://xr5.goncaloperes.com/).

For the Player, I am using the ThridPersonController from on [Standard Assets](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2017-3-32351)  - but I have hidden Ethan and added my own character/avatar.

[image: ThirdPersonController]

And this is the inspector of the avatar:

[image: Santa - Inspector]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When WebGL is not behaving the same as Unity player, something is conflicting.

In this case, as we can see from the images there are **2 animators** (one in each image) controlling for the **same purpose**.

The problem was solved by disabling the second animator (the one related with Santa - the avatar, that is inside the ThirdPersonController).